# Differentiating this “differential” equation with respect to a third variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I cannot figure out this differentiation step in this:

$$\begin{align}
\dot{\rho} + 3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\rho &= 0 \\
\implies \frac{1}{a^3} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\big(pa^3\big) &= 0
\end{align}$$

Apparently, its differentiating with respect to $t$ and the equation has a differential of $a$ and $\rho$ in the equation.

A web search isn't helpful because I am not aware what this is specifically called and any attempts just sends me to implicit differential which is something else.

Comment: $\dot{a}=da/dt$.

Comment: it's the product rule in reverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply says that $$\frac{1}{a^3}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(pa^3) = \frac{1}{a^3} \left(a^3\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(p) + p\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(a^3)\right) = \frac{1}{a^3} \left(a^3 \dot{p} + 3pa^2 \frac{da}{dt} \right) = \dot{p} + \frac{3p}{a}\dot{a}$$

i.e: just the product rule and the chain rule ($\frac{d}{dt}(a^3) = \frac{d}{da}(a^3) \frac{d}{dt}(a)$).

In the solution you're asking about, they've simply recognised that $\dot{p} + 3p\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$ could be 'reverse product rule' back to $\frac{1}{a^3}\frac{d}{dt}(pa^3)$ which is a convenient form. It's useful because you can now simply integrate both sides the equation and note that $\int \frac{d}{dt}(pa^3) \, \mathrm{d}t = pa^3$.